# how to send 10 python get requests in a burst

Tags: python, multithreading, api, request

I am trying to send 10 get requests in a burst.

The api docs says `Requests are throttled at 10 per minute with a burst allowance of 10.`

https://binlist.net/

This is what i am trying to do

```
list_of_urls=["https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456",
"https://lookup.binlist.net/123456"]


def get_url(url):
    return requests.get(url).text

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
    print(list(pool.map(get_url,list_of_urls)))
```

But this is still 10 get requests parallel right?
Isn't that different from 10 burst requests?

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from Linux netfilter documentation (edited by me). It documents the meaning of limit and burst. *Beware*: it is probably not what that website is using, but it gives you an idea how these terms are usually used in networking.

> Limit specifies the maximum average number of matches to allow per
> second.
>
> Butst is indicating the maximum burst before the above limit kicks in.
>
> Example rule: limit=3 per hour, burst=5
>
> The first time this rule is reached, the packet will be accepted; in
> fact, since the default burst is 5, the first five packets will be
> accepted. After this, it will be twenty minutes before a packet will
> be accepted from this rule, regardless of how many packets reach it.
> Also, every twenty minutes which passes without matching a packet, one
> of the burst will be regained; if no packets hit the rule for 100
> minutes, the burst will be fully recharged; back where we started.